# how to get parent URLs belonging to it's child categories?

Tags: categories

i wants to get parent url of child categories like this Example: PRODUCTS & SERVICES > ENTERTAINMENT > SURPRISE PROMO.

PRODUCTS & SERVICES is my parent category, and ENTERTAINMENT is PRODUCTS & SERVICES's child category, and SURPRISE PROMO is ENTERTAINMENT's child category. so i need to get full url like this "www.example.com/products-services/entertainment/surprise-promo"

```
{exp:channel:categories category_group="1"}
    <a href="{category_url_title}">{category_name}</a>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Please help how to get full URL,

thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on exactly what you want to see in your output, this is unclear as it's written.

Comment: i wants to get parent url of child categories like this 
Example: PRODUCTS & SERVICES > ENTERTAINMENT > SURPRISE PROMO
PRODUCTS & SERVICES is my parent category, and ENTERTAINMENT is PRODUCTS & SERVICES's child, and SURPRISE PROMO is ENTERTAINMENT's child. so i need to get full url like this "http://www.example.com/products-services/entertainment/surprise-promo"

Answer (score 2):

**[GW Code Categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories)** is pretty much my goto addon for anything to do with manipulating category output. It has useful parameters & variables for this type of stuff: `{complete_path}` & `{output_path}` which would work in your case. There is also an example of category based breadcrumbs:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="add-ons" limit="1"}
    <a href="{site_url}">Home</a> &raquo;
    {exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" style="linear"}
        {if group_start}<a href="{path="add-ons"}">{cat_group_name}</a> &raquo;{/if}
        <a href="{path="add-ons/{cat_url_title}"}">{cat_name}</a> &raquo;
    {/exp:gwcode_categories}
    {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You could also swap `{path="add-ons/{cat_url_title}"}` for `{complete_path}` as it will successively build the URL's in each anchor.